# Set Start Program in Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio-express

I want to run `Nuint` in Visual, so I set

```
<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>$(NUNIT_PATH)\nunit.exe</StartProgram>
<StartArguments>Test.dll</StartArguments>
<StartWorkingDirectory>Test\bin\Debug</StartWorkingDirectory>
```

in my csproj file. But it stll does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those entries look correct for the project file.  The most likely cause of the problem is that `$(NUNIT_PATH)` isn't properly set and hence gets evaluated to nothing.  This would cause Visual Studio to look for nunit.exe in the `Test\bin\Debug` directory.

To test this try hard coding the full path to the nunit.exe binary into the file.

```
<StartProgram>C:\the\path\nunit.exe</StartProgram>
```

If this works then the `NUNIT_PATH` value isn't properly set.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Express editions don't support the StartAction mechanism. See MSDN [How to: Change the Start Action for Application Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68c8335t.aspx).

I'm looking for alternatives though ;-)

Update see also [SO-a/10572249/717355](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572249/717355): Try http://www2.wealth-lab.com/Wiki/kbDebugExpress.ashx step 13 for a suggestion on making MSVC think its debugging your code directly. - Untried.